# Google API for fetching all registered business locations

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using Google Place API. My problem is that I want to show the business locations for a particular franchise whose store locations have already been registered and verified by Google. Can anyone please provide me with the steps to get the csv file in Android OS which we get on the browser by clicking the "Download All Locations" buttons. It's located in the left hand menu in "My Business Locations" page.

I tried to search the method to retrieve that but I wasn't able to hit the correct method or API for this purpose.

Please share any method to achieve this. Links or API are welcome as well. Anything that could help me to get this functionality done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this?

Comment: No, had moved all locations to local server,